# 80's/90's horror movie about a group of youngsters in a Mansion with plenty of monsters?

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Does anyone know the title of a movie about a group of youngsters in a Mansion with plenty of monsters. There are zombies, werewolves, creatures,... There's a part where the lord of the Manor gets stabbed in the forehead and in the end

> that same guy gets out of a crypt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"[Spookies](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090057/)" (1986)?

[image: Movie cover of Spookies]

It has a warlock, zombies, muck men, vampires and other assorted monsters in a mansion with young people, and the lord of the manor is a warlock. The warlock gets stabbed in the forehead at 1:10:48 in the film.

### Trailer

Comment: Thank you!!! I've been searching for this for more than 20 years! The Internet is so incredible :_)